# Add to cart after Login/Register

Tags: php, opencart

How can the system add to cart after login or register?
I already checked with the Session variable while not logged in. I want to add it after I login or register. How can I pass the variable to the login?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the OpenCart admin to only allow registered users to checkout. Then you can also make default users into a new group called "Force Users" or something. Assign items available to this group and only they can add those items to cart.

Comment: I think the question is about something completely different. He do not want to force customers to login/register. He just want to add some product automatically into the shopping cart if you do so (without forcing you to do so).